# Replace a value when it is empty (ZAPIER - Javascript)

Tags: zapier

I want to extract the 3 UTMs (utm_source, utm_medium, utm_campaign) from an URL and send them to the next step with this javascript code-step in zapier.

The javascript code worked perfectly:

```
    let url = inputData.URL;
 
    let queryString = url.split("?").pop();
    let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    let utm_source = urlParams.get('utm_source')
    let utm_campaign = urlParams.get('utm_campaign')
    let utm_medium = urlParams.get('utm_medium')
    let utm_term = urlParams.get('utm_term')
    let utm_content = urlParams.get('utm_content')
 
    output = [{url, queryString, utm_source, utm_campaign, utm_medium, utm_term, utm_content}];
```

The problem comes when the URL comes with no UTM.
In this cases the value is empty, so I want to replace it with a default value (for example "organic")

---

I started trying with something like this but it is not working:

```
if(utm_campaign === null || typeof utm_campaign === "undefined" || utm_campaign === "") {
utm_campaign = "ORGANIC";
}
```

Please, ¿can someone help me with this javascript code?
Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent opportunity to use the `ternary` [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
    let url = inputData.URL;
     
        let queryString = url.split("?").pop();
        let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
        let utm_source = urlParams.get('utm_source') ? urlParams.get('utm_source') : 'definitely not organic'
        let utm_campaign = urlParams.get('utm_campaign')
        let utm_medium = urlParams.get('utm_medium') ? urlParams.get('utm_medium') : 'organic'
        let utm_term = urlParams.get('utm_term')
        let utm_content = urlParams.get('utm_content')
     
        output = [{url, queryString, utm_source, utm_campaign, utm_medium, utm_term, utm_content}];
```

In this case, you can select a default per variable.